# Jquery count occurrences of class

Tags: jquery

I have a table with rows configured as :

```
<tr id='user0'><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr id='site0'><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr id='staff0'><td></td><td></td></tr>

<tr id='user1'><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr id='site1'><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr id='staff1'><td></td><td></td></tr>

<tr id='user2'><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr id='site2'><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr id='staff2'><td></td><td></td></tr>
```

The rows relate to a specific staff member, and each 'block' of rows has the id number increased.  Eg: user0,site0,staff0 - user1,site1,staff1  - user2,site2,staff2 etc...

Some of the row `<td>`'s may have a class assigned. eg:

```
<tr id='user0'><td></td><td class='error'></td></tr>
<tr id='site0'><td class='error'></td><td></td></tr>
<tr id='staff0'><td></td><td class='error'></td></tr>
```

How do I count all occurrences of that class for the 3 rows based on the ID number.  So in the above example the result would be 3

Thanks

Comment: you want to count error classes ? Not getting clearly

Comment: Easiest solution: Don’t do it based on what number the different ids end in, but give _all_ three elements a common class, 'itemX' or something like that. Then it’s as easy as `$('.itemX .error').length`

Comment: I want to count the number of times that error class is used for each 'block' of TR's

Comment: Use https://jsfiddle.net/mywzr1bx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want like this ?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tr0 = $("tr[id$=0] .error").length;
    var tr1 = $("tr[id$=1] .error").length;
    var tr2 = $("tr[id$=2] .error").length;
    console.log(tr0);
    console.log(tr1);
    console.log(tr2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the elements, find the ones with the given ids, and count the error classes:

```
function countItems(id) {
  var count = 0;
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("tr"), function(el) {
    if (parseInt(el.id.replace(/\D/g, ""), 10) === id) {
        count += el.querySelectorAll("td[class='error']").length;
    }
  });
  return count;
}

console.log(countItems(0)) // 3
```